# export data.frame in R into plain JSON

Tags: json, r, dataframe, export, jsonlite

I would like to export a simple data.frame in R into a plain JSON object, ideally append multiple vars to a data.js file.

This is my data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Person=c("Dan", "Tom", "Max"), Apples=c(3,5,8), Pears=c(1,0,2), Bananas=c(30,1,4))
df

  Person Apples Pears Bananas
1    Dan      3     1      30
2    Tom      5     0       1
3    Max      8     2       4
```

And this is the format I would like to export to.

```
var data1 = [
["Person", "Apples", "Pears", "Bananas"],
["Dan", 3, 1,30],
["Tom", 5, 0, 1],
["Max", 8, 2, 4],
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm tempted to ask "what have you tried ... ?" ...

This is tempting but doesn't work because `toJSON` handles the rows,
not the columns, as lists:

```
library(rjson)
cat(toJSON(df))
## {"Person":["Dan","Tom","Max"],
##    "Apples":[3,5,8],"Pears":[1,0,2],"Bananas":[30,1,4]}
```

`apply(df,1,...)` would be nice,  but `apply()` does a bunch of
simplification that it's hard to turn off.

```
tmp1 <- lapply(split(df,seq(nrow(df))),function(x) unname(as.list(x)))
cat(toJSON(c(list(names(df)),tmp1)))
## {"":["Person","Apples","Pears","Bananas"],
##    "1":["Dan",3,1,30],"2":["Tom",5,0,1],"3":["Max",8,2,4]}
```

This is not exactly the format you've requested but it's pretty close.